# cycle through Access fields to find the first empty

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table with 40 fields.  I need  to find the first instance of an empty field.

```
strSQL = "Select * FROM KeyLog WHERE LastName= '" & Forms!UserEdit.cboLastName & "' AND FirstName = '" & Forms!UserEdit.txtFirstName & "'"
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
  TxtLast = rs!LastName
  txtFirst = rs!FirstName

For i = 1 To 5
strKey = "key" & i & "Number"

MsgBox (rs! & strKey)
Next
```

just to see it would actually work pull the data (didn't expect it to, but I had to try).

How do I code it to cycle through each one without having to code each field to see if it is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the [`Fields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/fields-collection-dao) collection of the Recordset, e.g.:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fd As DAO.Field
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
        .MoveFirst
        For Each fd In .Fields
            If IsNull(fd.Value) Then
                MsgBox fd.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        Next fd
    End If
    .Close
End With

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```